# Put dropdown selection in variable and use in search query

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, xmlhttprequest

I have 2 pages I am working with, `index.php` and `dropdown-display.php`. I have a dropdown in `index.php` that sends the selection to `dropdown-display.php` and filters my HTML table. I also have a search box, and if a dropdown selection has already been made, I want it to search the already filtered results by using the dropdown value in the query as well.

So how can I incorporate the variable `$q` below (if a dropdown selection has been made) into my search query?

This is what I currently have...

Index.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search-species'])) {

// variable that brings in search value 
    $speciesToSearch = $_POST['SpeciesToSearch'];

// query used to filter results based on search 
    $sql = "SELECT *
        FROM Example_Final_Structure
        WHERE [Species] LIKE '%".$speciesToSearch."%'
        ORDER BY [Current-SKU] ASC";

} else {

    $sql = "SELECT *
        FROM Example_Final_Structure
        ORDER BY [Current-SKU] ASC";

}
?>
```

HTML in index.php:

```
<script>
// function that gets the value of the dropdown and sends it to display-dropdown.php to get results
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;

                var newTableObject = document.getElementById('millwork_table');
                sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","dropdown-display.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>

<form name="myForm" action="">
<section id="supp_name_dropdown" onchange="hide2()" align="center" >
    <select id="selectsupp" class="supp-name" data-attribute="supp" onchange="showUser(this.value)">                
        <option value="" selected disabled>Supplier Name</option>
        <?php foreach($drop->fetchAll() as $dropdown) { ?>
            <option class="sku-<?php echo $dropdown['Supplier-Name'];?>" value="<?php echo $dropdown['Supplier-Name'];?>"><?php echo $dropdown['Supplier-Name'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</section>
</form>



<section id="search-species">
<form method="post" action="index.php">

    <input name="SpeciesToSearch" class="search" type="text" placeholder="Species">
<span class="arrow"></span>
    <button type="submit" class="button" name="search-species" value="Search">Search</button><br>
</form>
</section>
```

Dropdown-display.php:

```
<?php
$q = ($_GET['q']); //variable that holds dropdown selection value

$sql="SELECT *
        FROM Example_Final_Structure
        WHERE [Supplier-Name] = '$q'";

?>
```

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thats all i have as far as sql queries, just the variable with the dropdown selection and a query to display the filtered data....i have html in order to display the table results but didnt think that played a big factor in my question

Comment: @IncredibleHat I am just unsure of how to use my `$q` variable, that holds the dropdown selection, in my search query that i already have...i already have the functionality down for filtering through search or filtering by dropdown selection.....i just want to be able to put that variable into my search query because right now, if i filter by dropdown, then search, the results displayed will completely disregard what was originally selected in the dropdown

Comment: Ok. I see. Well, sql-server is different than mysqli or PDO, so yeah, someone else will have to step in with how to properly safeguard the input variables from sql injection, and escaping issues. Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @IncredibleHat alright, no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your search form you could add a `<input type="hidden" id="searchsupp" name="searchsupp" value=""/>`

then en your `showUser` function, inject the value received to the hidden input. `document.getElementById("searchsupp").value = str;`

Then you can use this value in your search by adding it to your query

```
"SELECT *
 FROM Example_Final_Structure
 WHERE ".($searchsupp != "" ? "[Supplier-Name] = '".$searchsupp."' AND ")."[Species] LIKE '%".$speciesToSearch."%'
 ORDER BY [Current-SKU] ASC"
```

Where `$searchsupp` is the variable you make from the posted data.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I seem to be having a problem with this...do I add the `<input type="hidden" etc...` to my current search form in `index.php`? Also, should that query and `$searchsupp` variable be in `index.php` or my `dropdown-display.php` page?

Comment: it should all be in the `index.php` file. `$searchsupp`should be given the value of `$_POST['searchsupp']`